# In a fork() program what is executed first? Parent or child?

Tags: c, unix, fork

I don't know what is executed first in fork. For example I have this code:

```
int main() {
   int n = 1;
   if(fork() == 0) {
      n = n + 1;
      exit(0);
   }
   n = n + 2;
   printf(“%d: %d\n”, getpid(), n);
   wait(0);
   return 0;
}
```

What will this print on the screen?

```
1: 3
0: 4
```

or

```
0: 4
1: 3
```

Comment: Which result do you get?

Comment: No. I don't have any C compilers on my computer and I have to study of an exam.

Comment: I get only one line printed (see my answer below).

Comment: The code is flawed. `fork()` does not create a new thread which would share the `n` variable with the parent. It creates an entire new process, so `n = n + 1` will in co circumstances be visible in the parent process. To test which process executes first (if that still interests you), access a *shared* resource, such as a file, from both processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not specificed. It's up to the OS scheduler to decide which process to schedule first.

```
After a fork(), it is indeterminate which process—the parent
or the child—next has access to the CPU. On a multiprocessor system,
they may both simultaneously get access to a CPU.
```

Answer (score 3):

When I run this program, it only prints one line, instead of two, because it `exit()`s in the `fork()`'s block.

So the question is, did you forget a `printf()` in the `fork()`'s block, or shouldn't the `exit()` be there?

Comment: The code is correct... I just didn't knew exactly what it does. :)

Comment: If the code is correct, it will print only one line: `xxx: 3\n`, with xxx being the PID of the parent process.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make one process run before the other,try using sleep() system call.

Comment: That is a terrible way to synchronize processes (how long would you sleep for?). And it doesn't answer the real question here.

Comment: The question was already answered by Karoly Horvath, so I just wanted to add something to it. I just want him to know about sleep() system call.